# ParameterizedTypeReference usage

Tags: spring, resttemplate

this seems to be redundant and obvious question,but can anyone explain me the concept of ParameterizedType Reference  in rest template

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate` is deprecated, use `WebClient` instead. Anyways, `ParameterizedTypeReference` is used where the target type is a generic type. Consider this, the response body contains a `Set<SomeObject>`, you can not pass the generic type directly to `exchange` method because `Set<SomeObject>.class` is an invalid reference. In this case, you can use `ParameterizedTypeReference`. Below is an example:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<SomeObject>> someObject = 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<SomeObject>>() {};

ResponseEntity<Set<SomeObject>> response =
    restTemplate.exchange("uri", HttpMethod.GET, null, someObject);
```

Other way of doing this is encapsulating `Set<SomeObject>` into a wrapper and create getters and setters to that set. But I don't recommend using it.

Comment: what  does this empty class means                         ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<SomeObject>> someObject = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<SomeObject>>() {};

Comment: is there any specific reason using anonymous class ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<SomeObject>>() {};

Comment: Yes, that's how the type can be known at runtime. You can get hold on `T` from `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>` if there is an instance of it.